# How to get current operations in mongodb using the nodejs driver

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am using node js as front end and mongodb is as backend. I got successfull connection. But while trying to get all the process running in mongodb are throw error. My code is below.

```
var Db = require('mongodb').Db, Server = require('mongodb').Server;
        var db = new Db('admin', new Server(conf.host, conf.port));
        db.open(function(err, db1) {
            var adminDb = db1.admin();
            adminDb.authenticate(conf.user, conf.password, function(err, result) {
                if(result == true) {
                     var obj = adminDb.currentOp({"active":true});
                     console.log("output="+output);
                }

            });
    });
```

I am getting below error.

> TypeError: adminDb.currentOp is not a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want [`.command()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Db.html#command):

```
   adminDb.command({ "currentOp": 1, "active": true },function(err,result) {
       // code in here
   });
```

If you are ever looking for how things are "actually" executed, then go into the mongo shell and type the function without the `()` parentheses on the end. This will show you the definition.

I.E for `currentOp()`:

```
> db.currentOp

function (arg) {
        var q = {};
        if (arg) {
            if (typeof(arg) == "object")
                Object.extend(q, arg);
            else if (arg)
                q["$all"] = true;
        }

        var commandObj = {"currentOp": 1};
        Object.extend(commandObj, q);
        var res = this.adminCommand(commandObj);
        if (commandUnsupported(res)) {
            // always send legacy currentOp with default (null) read preference (SERVER-17951)
            var _readPref = this.getMongo().getReadPrefMode();
            try {
                this.getMongo().setReadPref(null);
                res = this.getSiblingDB("admin").$cmd.sys.inprog.findOne(q);
            } finally {
                this.getMongo().setReadPref(_readPref);
            }
        }
        return res;
    }
```

Comment: Also can you tell me how to get SLAVE STATUS of mongodb?

Comment: @selvan That would be another question. If you really need to, then [Ask One](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). But I have already told you that "most" things are actually a `.command()` and also how to inspect how various shell methods are actually implemented.

Comment: Yes. Created new question.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44082523/how-to-get-slave-status-of-mongodb-using-nodejs