# How to get slave status of mongodb using nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I want to get slavestatus of mongodb server using node js. Here is the code.

```
var Db = require('mongodb').Db, Server = require('mongodb').Server;
        var db = new Db('admin', new Server(conf.host, conf.port));
        db.open(function(err, db1) {
            var adminDb = db1.admin();
             adminDb.command({ "status": 1 },function(err,result) {
                  console.log("output="+result);
            });
    });
```

But i am getting error.

> error=MongoError: no such command: 'status', bad cmd: '{ status: 1 }'

Comment: Which operation are you trying to replicate? `rs.status()`?

Comment: You can probably save yourself a lot of trouble by taking the time to go through the complete list of [Database Commands](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/)

Comment: Yes. rs.status()

Comment: Bad idea to ignore errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That would be ["replSetGetStatus"](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/replSetGetStatus/)

```
admiDb.command({ "replSetGetStatus": 1 }, function(err,result) {

})
```

As noted there is a full list of [Database Commands](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/) in the core documentation. These are the "building blocks" of the BSON structure of what is sent to the server to initiate operations.

Just about everything in all driver implementations uses this command list. And all drivers provide a variant of `.command()` in order to issue them.

Comment: @selvan  That is the standard response if the server is not being run with that option. So your server is not a member of a replica set. You cannot get status from something that isn't in a replica set, therefore that is exactly the response you should receive. Start the server with the `--repltSet` option if you expect to see something different.