# Get connection status of my database in sails v0.12

Tags: javascript, sails.js, sails-mongo

I want to get the equivalent of `db.serverStatus()` command in mongo shell for Sails v0.12. In v1.0 I think they have `sails.getDatastore` for this. I searched the documentation for v0.12 and could not get an alternative. Is it possible to check the connection status of my database through sails v0.12 ?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/44083108/8850397

Comment: @SudarshanaDayananda I am using Sails.js, and in that we do not have direct access to the db instance. It is internally managed by the framework. Basically I  need a hook to that db instance object in Sails.js. Plain Nodejs code will not work for me. I do not want to write anything out of the framework. I know I will  be able to get my db status writing some NodeJs code outside the framework to connect to my db. But I want to know if there is a way I can get it without doing so.